# Angular component not recognized after bundling using Gulp

Tags: angular, gulp

I am trying to run my angular application after bundling using gulp. I have used custom components in my page which I have created. I am able to run my page locally but after bundling and minifying using gulp, the components which I have used in my page are not recognized.  I am getting error in console stating: 'mycomponent' is not a known element.

Points taken care of:

1. I have added this component in my module declarations
2. I have also tried reordering the components in declarations to have my component to be rendered first.
3. tried setting mangle=false in uglify()

Comment: If you want help as soon as possible, you'd better provide a way to reproduce your problem as soons as possible. We're not extra-lucid wizards. We can't explain a bug without seeing any code.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve this should explain what @JBNizet is trying to say. Provide some example to demonstrate your issue

Answer (score 0):

To me, "'mycomponent' is not a known element" implies it can't recognize the selector.

Ensure that you are declaring exactly this name in the class metadata of the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mycomponent',
  templateUrl: 'mycomponent.html',
  styleUrls: ['mycomponent.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

}
```

And in a parent component you could use it like this:

```
<mycomponent></mycomponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply Jim. 
The solution was close to what Jim mentioned. The issue was that my selector had camel casing. Gulp bundling does not distinguish camel-cased selectors and converts all of them to lower case in the html template. However the component definition had camel-cased selector. This was causing an issue to recognize the selector.

Child  component:
@Component({selector: 'mySelector'})

parent component HTML:

```
<mySelector></mySelector>
```

Bundled child component:
selector: 'mySelector'

Bundled parent component HTML:

```
**<myselector></myselector>**
```